# Save and Read Files to GridFS

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm quite new to MongoDB and Pyhton but I have a question to the following problem.

I would like to store some datafiles into gridfs, and later read the saved file out. The insert seams to funtion, cause I get a Objectid and also "see" the file in the DB.

```
#Insert external File into DB
def dbInsertFile():
    db = MongoClient().TestDB
    fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
    fileID = fs.put(open(r'../2_134_1_2_134_022_RTP05.mat_final.csv', 'rb'))
    print(fileID)
```

Gives an ObjectId: 5c6bcc8562b3d50742110562

As soone as I come to the line where I want to get the file with the fileID

```
def dbReadFile(fileID):
    db = MongoClient().TestDB
    fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
    file = fs.get(fileID)
    print(file)
```

i get the message:

```
gridfs.errors.NoFile: no file in gridfs collection Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True), 'TestDB'), 'fs.files') with _id '5c6bcc8562b3d50742110562'
```

Did I miss something to actually store the file in the database?

Hope someone can help me :-)

btw... where can I find the **kwargs in the mongo documentation that can be used for the put function?

Greatings
Alex

Answer (score 0):

GridOut instance is required for downloading the image locally. Use `'get_last_version'` method call if you are retrieving the image by its filename.

```
gout = self.fs.get_last_version('required filename')
```

Write the data locally. Open a file in write mode.

```
fout = open('filename of ur choice', 'wb')
fout.write(gout.read())
fout.close()
gout.close()
```

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the input method seems to be correct and I've to change the "export" method, right?

Comment: I've found a good site where all steps where descriped well: 
[link] (https://psabhay.com/2015/03/mongodb-gridfs-using-python/)